# getting error while adding controller in the mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Iam getting error while adding controller as 
        "Unable to retrieve meta data for MvcCustomer.ViewModels.ViewOrderData.Unable to load  the specialfied metadata resource".
Here is my viewmodel

```
          namespace MvcCustomer.ViewModels
          {
           public class ViewOrderData 
           {
            public IEnumerable<CustomerInfo> customerinfo { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<CustomerOrderData> customerorderdata { get; set; }
           }
         }
```

Trying to add the controller with MvcCustomer Class and DBContext but it is unabl to creating the controller.

Comment: Can you please post more code - thanks